# Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm in the process of upgrading my Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.7

I ran this `composer update`

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled

In RouteServiceProvider.php line 40:
                                         
  Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found  
                                         

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
⚡️  bheng  composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled

In RouteServiceProvider.php line 40:
                                         
  Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found  
                                         

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

> Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found

---

## RouteServiceProvider

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
     public function boot(){
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
             'middleware' => 'web',
             'namespace' => $this->namespace,
         ], function ($router) {
             require base_path('routes/web.php');
         });
     }

}
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't imported Route, so it's trying to find a class named Route in the current namespace.  Either import it with `use` underneath your namespace declaration or use the full path to the class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

---

You'll also want to get rid of clear-compiled in your composer.json file, it's not in 5.7.